# Relationship Between Subspace $V$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $m-n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I'm struggling with answering this question:

"Consider a subspace $V$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ that is defined by $n$ homogeneous linear equations:

$\begin{vmatrix}
           a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \cdots +a_{1m}x_m=0 \\
           a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \cdots +a_{2m}x_m=0 \\ \vdots\\
           a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 + \cdots +a_{nm}x_m=0 \\ \end{vmatrix}$

What is the relationship between the dimension of $V$ and the quantity $m - n$? State your answer as an inequality. Explain carefully."

I know this has to do with rank-nullity, but I'm having a hard time incorporating $dimV$ into the equation. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: $V$ can be expressed as a kernel of certain map...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you agree to consider each element of $\Bbb R^m$ as an column vector then you can define a map $T:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ by $T(x)=Ax$, where $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times m}$. Show that $T$ is a linear map and $\ker(T)=V$.
Using Rank-nullity theorem,  $$\text{Rank}(T)+\text{Nullity}(T)=m$$ and conclude that $$\dim (V)=m-\text{Rank}(T)\ge m-n$$ (also observe that $\text{Rank}(T)=\text{Rank(A)}$, which is easy to prove).